# graphene-django - How to filter?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I use graphen-django for build a GraphQL API.
I have succesfully create this API, but I can't pass a argument for filter my response.

This is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("nom", unique=True, max_length=255)
    sonarQube_URL = models.CharField("Url SonarQube", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

This is my **schema.py**:
    import graphene
    from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
    from models import Application

```
class Applications(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Application

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    applications = graphene.List(Applications)

    @graphene.resolve_only_args
    def resolve_applications(self):
        return Application.objects.all()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

My **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', authviews.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
]
```

As you can see, I also have a REST API.

My **settings.py** contains this:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'tibco.schema.schema'
}
```

I follow this: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django

When I send this resquest:

```
{
  applications {
    name
  }
}
```

I've got this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "applications": [
      {
        "name": "foo"
      },
      {
        "name": "bar"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

So, it's works!

But when I try to pass an argument like this:

```
{
  applications(name: "foo") {
    name
    id
  }
}
```

I have this response:

```
{
  "errors": [
   {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"applications\" of type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 16,
          "line": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i have missed? Or maybe I do something wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/

This is my answer. I have edit my **schema.py**:

```
import graphene
from graphene import relay, AbstractType, ObjectType
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField
from models import Application

class ApplicationNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        filter_fields = ['name', 'sonarQube_URL']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(ObjectType):
    application = relay.Node.Field(ApplicationNode)
    all_applications = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ApplicationNode)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Then, it was missing a package: django-filter (https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/tree/master).
Django-filter is used by DjangoFilterConnectionField.

Now I can do this:

```
query {
  allApplications(name: "Foo") {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the response will be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allApplications": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're in my case and don't want to use Relay, you can also handle filtering directly in you resolvers using Django orm filtering. Example here: [Filter graphql query in django](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/7-filtering/)

Comment: It's insane that there's a coupling to replay in the otherwise-generic sounding `DjangoListField`

Answer (score 4):

Little addition to Adrien Answer. If you want to perform different operation while filtering like contains and exact match then edit your **schema.py**

```
class ApplicationNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        # Provide more complex lookup types
        filter_fields = {
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith']
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

and you can write the query like this

```
  query {
  allApplications(name_Icontains: "test") {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```